# How can I resolve this error "uncommitted xmin 1358613895 from before xid cutoff 1601650960 needs to be frozen"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, enterprisedb

I am getting the errors below in my postgresql log files. Seeking assistance on how to fix them.

PostgreSQL version is 9.6

==> postgresql-2020-03-10.log <==

```
2020-03-10 10:48:19 EAT|||ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 1358613895 from before xid cutoff 1601650960 needs to be frozen
2020-03-10 10:48:19 EAT|||CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "schema.public.tablename"
```

==> postgresql-2020-03-10.csv <==

```
2020-03-10 10:48:19.140 EAT,,,22943,,5e67463b.599f,1,,2020-03-10 10:48:11 EAT,13/281,0,ERROR,XX001,"uncommitted xmin 1358613895 from before xid cutoff 1601650960 needs to be frozen",,,,,"automatic vacuum of table "schema.public.tablename"
```

Comment: See similar discussion for same issue:   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950050/postgres-uncommitted-xmin-from-before-xid-cutoff-needs-to-be-frozen]

Comment: Zero damaged pages leads to data loss so I am hesitant to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you would like to verify:

1. Find any long opened prepared transaction

```
    SELECT * FROM pg_prepared_xacts ;
```

2. Check if you have any open transaction with 1358613895

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE backend_xid = 1358613895 OR backend_xmin = 1358613895
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE now() - xact_start <= INTERVAL '1 days'
```

If you find any long transaction using above SQLs then cancel the transaction. In case you are not able to find any long transaction, then you could one of the following:
  a. Shutdown the Postgres and run PostgreSQL in single-user mode and perform the VACUUM Operation.
  b. In one transaction, perform the following operations

```
     BEGIN;
     CREATE TABLE public.tablename_copy AS SELECT * FROM public.tablename;
     TRUNCATE TABLE public.tablename;
     INSERT INTO public.tablename SELECT * FROM public.tablename_copy;
     DROP TABLE public.tablename_copy;
     END;
```

```
 -- OR ---
```

```
     BEGIN;
     COPY public.tablename TO '/tmp/tablename.data';
     TRUNCATE TABLE public.tablename;
     COPY public.tablename FROM '/tmp/tablename.data';
     END;
```

Perform

```
VACUUM FREEZE ANALYZE;
```